# Tie camera location/view to texture appearance?

Tags: node-editor, camera, color

my last question was too difficult so this hopefully this will be easier to answer :p

**Is there a way to use a camera view or location data to determine whether or not a color/texture appears?**

---

I plan to use a node equation that takes a blue color channel, and the higher the blue value, the easier the texture would show.

[image: A simple node setup]

*My end result would be looking like this, except the bright areas would be moved my the camera/view, rather than light rotation.*

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UJ9G.jpg

**The setup is easy to replicate so I don't see the need for a .blend file, you could just texture paint certain parts of a sphere or cube blue to get the same result.**

I hope this isn't too complicated since I have a tendency to ramble in my questions, I'd be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are looking for a channel which describes the angle of a surface with respect to the camera view. This is achieved by the *Layer Weight* and *Fesnel* nodes, found in the *Input* node category. The mixing can be controlled using the facing or IOR values of the Layer Weight and Fresnel nodes as well as a Color Ramp or Map Range node further tweaking/contrast. See the following node setup:

[image]

Comment: Omg, THANK YOU. It always ends up being a simple solution to my shader problems lol, this is exactly what I needed.